# Why is ContentType header exposed as a distinct property?

Tags: asp.net-core

Without built in parsing to split the media type identifier from the media type parameters it likely that developers will do naïve comparisons between media type values and content types leading to false negative matches.

Answer (score 3):

This issue is being [tracked](https://github.com/aspnet/HttpAbstractions/issues/19). We will review and update as appropriate

Comment: Not sure what you mean. This is a bug/workitem tracked by the link I posted.

Comment: My mistake, guess I reviewed to quickly because it is a very short answer. I didn't relate "known work item" as "know issue". Your update makes it more clear.